# How to experiment using majority voting in Weka

Tags: machine-learning, weka

I am working on human action recognition from video.

I want to experiment my SVM and Random Forest classifiers in the following way:

- Calculate feature vectors from each image in the input videos separately.
- For training: Feature vector of each image from training videos is used with the label equal to the label of the video  it belongs to
- For testing (use **majority voting**) : for classifying a test video, all of its images are classified separately and give vote to its label. The label with the most votes will be chosen as the label for the test video.

I want to implement this in Weka. I have searched but only found Weka's Vote which can only be used to combine different classifiers (not in the way I want).

Answer (score 0):

I see, you want to combine multiple results from a single classifier into one through voting, while Weka's voting classifier is designed to combine individual results from multiple classifiers.

You probably already arrived at the same conclusion, but, anyway, you'd probably have to implement a custom Weka filter for that, that would combine multiple results into one through voting.